# Disable syslog remote connections

Tags: networking, freebsd, syslog

I'm securing a server and closing all the ports that are not used, but i can't close the syslogd port, even worse I cannot find where the syslogd is called.

This is what sockstat shows me:

```
USER    COMMAND PID FD  PROTO   LOCAL ADDRESS   FOREIGN ADDRESS
root    syslogd 746 7   udp4    *:514           *:*
root    sshd    628 4   tcp4    *:22            *:*
```

and the rc.conf:

```
defaultrouter="192.168.15.1"
ifconfig_dc0="inet 192.168.15.107 netmask 255.255.255.0"
# hostname
hostname="xxxxx"
sshd_enable="YES"
# Set dumpdev to "AUTO" to enable crash dumps, "NO" to disable
dumpdev="AUTO"
```

I only need the sshd service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can disable remote logs adding the following line to the file '/etc/rc.conf'.

```
syslogd_flags="-s"
```

Or use this one to close the network sockets:

```
syslogd_flags="-ss"
```

After added the syslogd_flags you can use this command to restart the service:

```
service syslogd restart
```